# Overloads cannot differ only by return type

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm trying to overload a function so when using the function somewhere else, it will show the result properly that is either an array of items, void, or a single item:

```typescript
getSelected(type): void;
getSelected(type): IDataItem;
getSelected(type): IDataItem[];
getSelected(type:string, one:boolean = true):any {
   if (!type) {
       return;
   }
   if (one) {
      return _.reduce<IDataItem, IDataItem>(sections[type], (current: IDataItem, p: IDataItem) => {
         return p.selected === true ? p : current;
      }, void 0);
   }

   return _.filter<IDataItem>(sections[type], (p: IDataItem):boolean => {
     return p.selected === true && p.enabled === true;
   });
}
```

It's giving me the error **"error TS2175: Overloads cannot differ only by return type."**. How can I just signal the many possibilities for the return types then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is worth noting a couple of points about your original code...

## You cannot call the implementation signature.

These are "overload signatures" - you can call these.

```
getSelected(type): void;
getSelected(type): IDataItem;
getSelected(type): IDataItem[];
```

The next line is the "implementation signature" - you cannot call it directly.

```
getSelected(type:string, one:boolean = true):any {
```

This means that as it stands, you cannot ever pass the `one` argument.

## You need to type the `type` parameter.

Your overloads don't specify a type for the `type` parameter, these will have the `any` type - but I think you probably want to restrict this to strings. Each signature needs the annotation...

```
type: string
```

## Differ based on boolean argument value

Your signature that states that *if you pass `true`* in the `one` argument, you'll get a single result. If you were to pass false, you'd get multiple results. We can now work with that, because TypeScript has been made *even more awesome*. See below...

## Working overloads.

Given all this information, you can use:

```
getSelected(type: string): void;
getSelected(type: string, one: true): IDataItem;
getSelected(type: string, one: false): IDataItem[];
getSelected(type: string, one: boolean = true): any {
    // ... code!
}
```

When you call this, the types will be inferred based on the arguments passed. This is the shape of it, with your code removed from the actual method...

```
interface IDataItem {
    name: string;
}

class Example {
    getSelected(type: string): void;
    getSelected(type: string, one: true): IDataItem;
    getSelected(type: string, one: false): IDataItem[];
    getSelected(type: string, one: boolean = true): void | IDataItem | IDataItem[] {
        // ... code!
    }
}

const example = new Example();

// void return
example.getSelected('just type');

// IDataItem
const a = example.getSelected('x', true);

// IDataItem[]
const b = example.getSelected('x', false);
```

Comment: This answer might be obsolete. Please take a peek at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729108/how-to-ensure-typescript-that-stringstring-is-string-without-using-as) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Use generics in order to help the compiler to determine the right value:

```
getSelected<T>(type:string, one:boolean = true): T {
    // ...
}

getSelected<void>('abc');
var aDataItem = getSelected<IDataItem>('abc');
var aList = getSelected<IDataItem[]>('abc');
```

[See also the documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics).

Comment: it seems I can't use generics on class members... any work around? it's giving me TS2011: Type "IDataItem" is not assignable to type "T"

Comment: Not a bad suggestion - although as your code example shows, there is a slight hitch. You call the method with `'abc'` in both calls, but expect to get a different return type, which is highly unlikely. Of course, you can update the sample code - but this behaviour would still be the case.

Comment: OK, the solution suggested by Steve and Ryan is better. If you know the return type at compile time, so you should avoid to again test the type at run time.

Comment: Personally, I like the sharpness of *Tarh* better than the latino sounding *Paleo* but it's your choice how you call yourself. :)    As for the technical part, would you say that [the other answer based on generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59729563/1525840) is too picky and restrictive?

Comment: @KonradViltersten `function getI18n<A extends string[] | string>(id: A): A` is OK. I personally use the same tricks in my code when appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If you might return anything based on the *content* of data passed in, and there's no common type between those possible return values, you should declare your return type to be `any` and force the calling code to use a type assertion.

I don't like Paleo's suggestion because it implies type safety where there is none.

Returning different types of data from a single function call is a code smell; it puts a lot of onus on the caller to understand what the relationship is between the inputs and the outputs. You'd be better off having something like `getSelectedSingle`, `getSelectedMultiple`, and `getSelectedNone`.

Comment: I see, I'm really "accustomed" with loose Javascript, and I need to change my mindset when working with Typescript (that's the main reason I'm doing the change)

Comment: This answer might be obsolete. Please take a peek at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729108/how-to-ensure-typescript-that-stringstring-is-string-without-using-as) for details.

Comment: Also, what is *tarh*? I checked the page for posts from a user by that name but found none.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It was my first pseudo here. So I edited this answer to change my own name. ;-)