# How to ensure TypeScript that string|string[] is string without using as?

Tags: typescript, types

**edit**
Due to course of time, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022331/overloads-cannot-differ-only-by-return-type)  has lost its validity, as it seems from the comments and answers to this one. Despite initial appearance, it's not a dupe of this one.

I had a translator function that worked by the following signature.

```
getI18n(id: string) : string { ... }
```

I noticed that typing the following was a bit tedious.

```
const titles = [
  this.util.getI18n("Donkey"),
  this.util.getI18n("Monkey"),
  ...
  this.util.getI18n("Wonkey")
];
```

I prefer to use something like this.

```
const titles = this.util.getI18n(["Donkey", "Monkey", ..., "Wonkey"]);
```

So I introduced a function that accepts *string* and *string[]* with the following signature.

```
getI18n(id: string | string[]) : string | string[] { ... }
```

That felt genius until I noticed that I have to explain for the stupid Typescript that the result is *string* and not some mumbo jumbo *string or string array* thingy, ending up with this (for the non-array translations).

```
someValue.replace("xxx", this.util.getI18n("Donkey") as string);
```

Is there a way to explain for TypeScript that the output **is *string*** even if it **might be *string[]*** in other cases?

Comment: Use two different functions (getI18n, and getI18ns), since they do something different. Or use an overloaded function: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads. TypeScript is not stupid at all: your function declaration says that your function sometimes return a string and sometimes returns a string[].

Comment: Overloading is a nice idea, but it will not work, as "All overloads must have same return type" - https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/

Comment: @JBNizet I (partly) disagree with your point based on the following. It's a valid feature of TS to allow indefinite return types. Based on the paradigm of JS (which TS transpiles to), the intrepretor should try to assume the best case. So I'd argue that the method should see *oh, it **actually might** be a string* rather than *oh no, it's **possible** it isn't a string*. This felt a bit too much C#'ish. Also, would you point me to a resource on overloading that allows indefinite return types? All I've found is receiving indefinites, not returning them. And **that** part works dandy in my case.

Comment: @Suma That link is for Java. not Java**Script** isn't it? Did you confuse *ham* and *ham**ster*** or is it my slow brain that doesn't catch your point?

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, it is a TypeScript. The article is called "TypeScript Function or Method Overloading". Only the web site has Java in the name.

Comment: @Suma Ah, all right, then. I got suspicious by the name of the site **in combination** with the second conditional in the example: *typeof paramTwo != 'undefined')*. Whenever I see "*==*" or "*!=*", I get paranoid thinking that it's not a reliable JS/TS author but someone who doesn't get the difference. (I do understand that sometimes the shorter syntax may actually what's intended but I'm still to be mistaken in that regard in practice, hehe...) Thanks!

Comment: @Suma I thought it did but as it turns out based on the answers/comments, it actually might be possible, so I'm not sure if marking it as a dupe does more good or more bad... Community vote will decide.   :) Either way, turned out to be an interesting topic for many members. Such is always nice.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ That question has already been linked and responded to. Please see the edit of my question and stop marking everything as a dupe that eagerly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve the effect by generic type property. Consider:

```
function getI18n<A extends string[] | string>(id: A): A { 
    return id; // example implementation
}

const arr = getI18n(['a', 'b']) // arr is string[]
const str = getI18n('a') // str is string
```

---

### The downside of generic approach

As the solution works great for id function, the issue starts with any implementation, TS is complaining about types as if the only way is to pass arguments without any modifications.
Consider:

```
function getI18n<A extends string[] | string>(id: A): A { 
    if (typeof id === 'string') {
        return id.concat('suffix') as A; 
    } else {
        return (id as string[]).map(x => x.concat('suffix')) as A;
    }
}
```

The solution works nice, but we need to consider some things:

- type assertions need to be used in the body of the function
- code not shows nicely what input type maps to what output (overloads show that)
- type inference of the output will wrongly infer type of input

The last point issue can be viewed in the example below:

```
const str = getI18n('a') // str is type "a"
```

So output type is "a" but in example implementation result will be a string "asuffix", so the type is wrong.

### Don't do that, function should have one input type

I want to add one thing to the whole topic. The fact that we have the demand to have such polymorphic input is generally inherited with common JS approach, were such things are considered as historically good practice. But in reality function which has specific one input will be better, it creates less confusion and questions.

Create function with monomorphic type.

```
function getI18n(ids: string[]): string[] { 
    return ids.map(id => id + "suffix");
}

const arr = getI18n(['a', 'b'])
const str = getI18n(['a'])
```

Simple as that. Benefits of the approach:

- no conditions on type level
- no conditions on value level
- no questions - what f will return for such and such input

There is really no cost in putting a string into array brackets.

Comment: Just to be super-clear as to the implementation. You mean that instead of *return id*, it should be something like *if(typeof(A==="string"))return doString(id);return doArray(id);*, right? If so, it should be amended to the answer as it might be confusing to noobs. I can put it in if you wish. But I prefer to get your confirmation that I got your point right so I won't tamper with good answer making it worse.

Comment: You said you have problem with type inference. How you do the body of the function will not impact the type, typeof checks are runtime checks. But if we ask how to implement this then yes you need to check if input is string somehow and typeof is good idea. But form TS point of view it's not doable to understand if your implementation will be correct, you could even do that reversed like for string return array and TS would not complain

Comment: You're perfectly correct and that' show I got your point. My request is based on a junior colleague who didn't understood the trick and questioned my interpretation. They suggested that it's sufficient to simply return whatever was sent in as if your example implementation was practically functional (it's valid syntactically, of course) while I maintain that it's but trivial (as not relevant to the actual question).

Comment: Of course, I won't horse around with your contribution if you don't see it fit. Just bringing different views into the discussion. The point of an answer is primarily to help (preferably being correct).   :)

Comment: I'd need your opinion on the comment you made to the other reply. I need to accept one of the answers and can't decide which one. You spoke in favor of it and against yours but I'm not entirely sure I agree with you there.

Comment: Also, when I came to think of it - is it necessary to do *(id as A & string[])*? I mean that *as string[]* is required so that *map(...)* knows that it's an iteratable thing but what is the purpose of *as A* in that context (given that the whole output of *map* is then *as*'ed to *A*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes `A & string[]` was not needed. Ok so there are issues in generic approach. Issues are: a lot of type assertion inside, not clearly visible connection between input -> output (overloads show nicely this connection), and also there are issues with types which are returned from generic function. Lets say I pass "a" to the function, the issue is that return will say the type is "a" not string.

Comment: An excellent point and very well supported. However, there **is** a cost to putting a string into brackets. It's a pain of pains when my *const headers* is defined like *[this.service.getI18n("header1"), this.service.getI18n("hader2"),...]*. I can introduce a helper method or simply *map(...)* it in but due to irregularities in my particular case, it makes a lot of sense to keep an array-translator. Nevertheless, again - you make an excellent point.

Answer (score 5):

Besides generics you can use function overloading

```
function getI18n(id: string[]): string[];
function getI18n(id: string): string;
function getI18n(id: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    if (typeof id === 'string') {
        return id + '_title';
    }
    return id.slice();
}

const title = getI18n('test'); // const title: string
const titles = getI18n(['a', 'b', 'c']); // const titles: string[]
```

Link to official docs on this feature: [functions overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

Comment: Are you sure? All articles I have read state all overloads must have the same return type.

Comment: .. but testing in the https://www.typescriptlang.org/play with TypeScript v3.7.2 seems it is really working. Perhaps the articles I have read are old and the restriction was lifted meanwhile? If this could be confirmed and added into the answer, it would be great.

Comment: One article specifically mentioning this technique: https://engineering.datorama.com/demystifying-function-overloading-in-typescript-eb9f8ca6b87d Still, it would be interesting to find if this has changed, or if perhaps the other articles (like https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/) have been wrong.

Comment: Recent specs certainly allow this: "if the candidate list contains one or more signatures for which the type of each argument expression is a subtype of each corresponding parameter type, the return type of the first of those signatures becomes the return type of the function call." https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.15

Comment: I think this is the best solution. No need for type assertions.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I'm not sure I agree with your rejection of generics due to assertion requirement. We're only asserting inside the method while the output will be understood properly automagically, won't it? While I appreciate the solution by overloading by its straight-forward nature, I sense certain distrust in multiplying the number of methods. In particular, I view the option of additional types being regarded and producing each their own type of output. If those can be treated by the same syntax and we only need to make TS STFU about uncertainty of the type, we'll go WET. What do you think?