# Typescript: one or several arguments of particular types in a method

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to specify one argument of specific type or several arguments of specific types for a method in typescrpt like so:

```
// args might be an instance
// of class Vector3, 
// for example, {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 }

// or args might be just three arguments,
// like so (x: number, y: number, z: number)
setPosition(args: SomeType): void {
  // 
}
```

I know, I can do something like this (with tuple):

```
setPosition(Vector3 | [number, number, number]): void {
  // 
}
```

But, then I need to use it with braces, like so:

```
setPosition([0, 1, 0]);
```

Is it possible to create types for arguments to safely use the method like so?

```
setPosition(0, 1, 0);

// or
const vec3 = new Vector3(0, 1, 2);
setPosition(vec3);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: And why not decide on one interface. What gives you having both? [a,b,c] is isomorphic to a,b,c.

Comment: I applaud trying to give an API flexibility, but @MaciejSikora is correct: pick one. I'd stick with a 3-Tuple/class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729108/how-to-ensure-typescript-that-stringstring-is-string-without-using-as/59729563#59729563

Answer (score 1):

You can use function overloading for this purpose:

```ts
function setPosition(a: Vector3): void;
function setPosition(a: number, b: number, c: number): void;
function setPosition(...args: [Vector3] | [number, number, number]): void {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Do you need the overloads?  What's wrong with `function setPosition(...args: [Vector3] | [number, number, number]): void {}`?

Comment: From a technical point of view there is no difference, but I think the definition of appropriate overloads makes it easier to understand (and read) how to use the method (for someone who hasn't written the code).